# jQuery scrollTop not working for a HTML element with height and scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

So I have the flowing HTML:

```
<div class="textconvo col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div class="row sender">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            Heather Harris
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            sun
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 6:58 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            robert
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            dfgdfgdfgdfg
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 8:31 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            robert
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            assdfsdfsdf
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 8:57 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            robert
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            sdfsdfsdf
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 8:58 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            robert
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            sdfsdfsdf
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 8:58 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            robert
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            sdfsdfsdfsdf
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 8:58 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            robert
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            sdfsdfsdf
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 8:58 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            robert
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            sdsdf
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 9:06 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            robert
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            sdfsdfsdf
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 9:06 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            robert
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            fdgdfgdfg
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            11/21/2014 9:31 PM
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 <div style="display: none;" id="newMessagePlaceHolder-3665048123427363225"></div>
            </div>
```

And the this CSS:

```
 .textconvo
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -ms-overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 300px;
}
```

And the this jQuery called on document.ready:

```
  $('.textconvo').each(function () {
        $(this).scrollTop($(this)[0].scrollHeight); //scrollHeight = 0
        $(this).scrollTop(500); //this doesn't work either
    });
```

I have done this scrollTop before in other apps and it has worked, the div.textconvo is in the DOM.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any errors on the page?  Check your debug output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested your code and it works, maybe you don't have jQuery loaded as `$`.

Check it out here [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/krfz9rpm/1/).

Comment: No I do have jQuery loaded as $